# Is the refractive index of a polymer less than that of a metal?

Tags: optics, refraction

I have asked this question because I am confused. Does metal have an index of refraction if waves such as light could not pass through it?

Comment: Light happily propagates through thin metal films. It’s just that some gets absorbed along the way.

Comment: In that sense, is there a range or approximation of their refractive index? For instance, an aluminum?

Comment: Is it greater than 1?

Comment: Googling ‘optical properties of aluminum’ brings up a variety of papers. Not sure which you can access, so I’ll let you choose.

Answer (score 2):

You are used to the simplest form of the index of refraction, the one used in transparent materials. It describes the ratio of the speed of light in the material to the speed of light in vacuum. That property turns out be important for how light changes direction at the boundary of a material. It is widely used to design lenses and such.

For metals, it isn't quite correct to say that light just reflects at the surface. It can penetrate, but it is very strongly absorbed as it goes. Some light can travel all the way through a metal film a few microns thick. So you can talk about the index of refraction of a metal.

For a metal, you can use a complex number for index of refraction. The imaginary part describes how quickly light is absorbed. This part is very small for most transparent materials. It is generally treated as $0$ and ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Refractive index of metals is not very intuitive. It varies from 0.05 (Ag, Cs) to 3, 4, or more.  https://refractiveindex.info/ has all the data you'll ever need, including polymers: polyvinyl chloride  has $n=1.525$